# msn live messenger video/webcam ports

Tags: video, webcam, windows-live-messenger

In a router without UPnP support, which ports should be forwarded for voice and video chat ?

[A Microsoft knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324214) states that UDP ports 5004 through 65535 should be forwarded, is that really the case? Is there a way to allow video traffic without opening a **huge** range of ports for incoming traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coppyed directly from an ad for some messenger blocking software:
Windows Live Messenger is an updated version of MSN Messenger and uses similar ports. As part of a forum to Microsoft's web site and other web sites (e.g. www.cyberphaze.net - not currently online) it seems that Windows Live Messenger uses:

> Messenger server: port 1493, 1542, 1863, 1963, 80 TCP and 443 TCP
>   File Transfer/Sharing Folders: local: 1544 and 6891 - in fact 6720-65535 TCP from one source
>   Messenger Update: remote: 80 local: 1457
>   Remote Assistance If available): 3389 TCP
>   Audio: local: , 1556, 11771, 13803 and generally 5004-65535 UDP
>   Remote Desktop and whiteboard: local/remote: 389, 522, 1503, 1720, and 1731
>   Launching Games: 80
>   Video Conference: TCP 9000-9999, 5004-65535 UDP + 80
>   Sign-In: remote: 443 local: 1484, 2400

Note - blocking TCP port 80 will stop users accessing web sites using Internet Explorer and other browsers.

Now it can USE all of these ports but you only need to port foward a small range, the systems are dynamic and if one port is open it will try to use that one.

Comment: no point???....i worked hard googling your anwser...